# What should my MaxRequestWorkers and server limits be set to in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, centos6

I recently got this error when restarting Apache2.4 on my Centos 6.9 server:

```
AH00316: WARNING: MaxRequestWorkers of 768 is not an integer multiple of 
ThreadsPerChild of 25, decreasing to nearest multiple 750, for a maximum of 30 
servers.
```

from what Ive read I believe that I need to make changes in /etc/apache2/conf.modules.d and then I need to make changes to mod_mpm_worker and this is what I have in that file right now:

```
/etc/apache2/conf.modules.d/000_mod_mpm_worker.conf
# Enable mod_mpm_worker
LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so
```

so do I just add whatever changes I want to make to MaxRequestWorkers etc there and how do I know what limits to use? This is a server with 40GB RAM and 24 cores with about 30 virtual hosts/sites running on it.

thanks

Comment: depends largely on the modules you use and if you are using modules which do language interpreting. Examine the resources consumed by each process and decide for yourself. 768 max workers is certainly not much, increase it.

Comment: ok but how or where do I make these changes? Do I just add a line for MaxRequestWorkers to 000_mod_mpm_worker.conf and then restart httpd? The official docs arent very clear on this.

Comment: the official docs tell you about "context" that's where directives go, in their respective context, probably all mpm related directives go in "server config" context, which is basically "not nested" inside any directory/virtualhost tag, etc. Files you use for configuration do not matter much, only context. Here see one of my examples: [single-httpd.conf](https://github.com/ezra-s/single-file-httpd.conf/blob/master/httpd.conf) . Here you can see everything needed for a whole working httpd server in a single file and separated by their meaningful context.